# Error al compilar typescript con visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, compilador

Estoy intentando iniciar en `typescript` y tengo unos problemas.

Antes que nada algunos datos:

Tengo instalada la version 1.11.2 del Visual Studio Code
Y estoy corriendo Node 6.5.0
junto con `typescript` en su versión 2.2.2

El problema que tengo es que al intentar compilar con <kbd>Ctrol</kbd>**+**<kbd>Shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>B</kbd>, en la salida veo el siguiente error:

```
error TS5014: Failed to parse file 'tsconfig.json': Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0.
```

Dejo una copia de mi archivo tsconfig.json aqui debajo

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "outDir": "build"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Ademas dejo un [**rar**](http://staging.mdiconcept.com/intercambio/typescriptjs.rar) adjunto con el proyecto de prueba

Imagino que debe ser un problema en mi configuración o algo que me estoy saltando, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba quitando el comentario, hasta donde se, TypeScript no permite comentarios en el archivo de configuración.

Comment: muchas gracias, ese era el problema, como di vueltas con esto...saludos

Comment: @Pablo si la respuesta de jvilla98a ayudó a solucionarte el problema recuerda marcala como respuesta aceptada, así te ayudas tu y ayudas a la comunidad